# Unexpected result when looping over List<Action>

Tags: c#, delegates, action

I'm currently looking for tricky interview snippets and I found two that I cannot explain. I merged them together so they can be run at the same time.

Here is the code:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var intActions = new List<Action>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            intActions.Add(() => { Console.WriteLine(i); });

        foreach (var action in intActions)
            action();


        string[] strings = { "abc", "def", "ghi" };
        var stringActions = new List<Action>();
        foreach (string str in strings)
            stringActions.Add(() => { Console.WriteLine(str); });

        foreach (var action in stringActions)
            action();
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
4
4
4
4
abc
def
ghi
```

Can anyone explain me why is the result like this? I'd expect four "4"s with four "ghi"s or "0123" and "abc def ghi"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why you are seeing `4444` and not `0123`, & `ghi ghi ghi` instead of `abc def ghi` is due to **closures**.

The `i` variable passed to the delegate is passed by **reference** and not by **value** which means that all of the actions will point to the same memory location for variable `i` & the latest value for `i` (set to 4 on the last iteration of the loop).

For the output to be `0123`, copying the variable to another temp variable would mean each action would have a pointer to a separate memory location, and thus yield the numbers as 'expected'.

```cs
var intActions = new List<Action>();
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    int copy = i;
    intActions.Add(() => { Console.WriteLine(copy); });
}

foreach (var action in intActions)
    action();
```

The same concept applies to the second part of your example:

```
string[] strings = { "abc", "def", "ghi" };
var stringActions = new List<Action>();
foreach (string str in strings) {
    var copy = str;
    stringActions.Add(() => { Console.WriteLine(copy); });
}

foreach (var action in stringActions)
    action();
```

Comment: Does it apply only to actions, or happens the same if I pass my value type variable to a regular CW? When it runs, CW gets the reference of the variable AND copies it THEN runs the body?

Comment: @BeholdTheLight What's CW? Try it and find out in any case.

Comment: I just wanted to make Console.WriteLine a bit shorter. Btw, thank you for the explanation.

Comment: Oh, CW is console write line! This only applies to the delegate, you can just do a `Console.WriteLine` of the variable outside of an action and it'll work as expected.